Maximum number of enclosed gaps/holes between touching circles
What is the maximum number of enclosed gaps/holes between $n$ touching circles? To ask it more formally:
Consider a family of $n$ closed balls (discs) in $\mathbb{R}^2,\ \{B_j(z_j;r_j)\}_{j=1}^n,$ where for each ball, $z_j$ is the coordinates of the centre and $r_j$ is the radius. The balls are almost pairwise disjoint, except their boundaries may touch. What is the maximal number of connected components of $\displaystyle\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n B_j(z_j;r_j)\right) ?$
Discs may have different radii.
I suspect that for $n\geq 3,$ the maximum number of holes is $2n-5,$ which means the number of connected components of $\displaystyle\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n B_j(z_j;r_j)\right)$ is $(2n-5)+1=2n-4,$ by "having the next circle fill a hole", but I remain sceptical without a proof.

First illustrative diagram a maximum possible one hole/gap between three discs (coloured in red):

You could also say that there are $1+1=2$ connected components of the complement of the union of the discs; the hole/gap, and everything outside the union of the discs and the hole.
I guess the problem is the same if we remove the condition, "balls/discs are not allowed to intersect", because allowing them to intersect shouldn't (I think) prevent any settings where we have a maximal number of holes.

Second illustrative diagram:

I count $7$ holes/gaps, which I think is the best we can do with $n=6$ circles. Going "inwards" like this seems to be the best strategy, but I don't know how to prove this.

Furthermore, I don't think a strategy like this will be maximal:

because the "going inwards strategy" seems to be better at maximising the number of holes, but I am not coming up with the reasoning why alternative strategies like this one are not maximal.

By gaps/holes do you mean regions? Do the circles only touch pairwise tangentially, with no intersection? Have you tried small cases and checked if there is a sequence in OEIS that describes it?

You can call them regions if you want. Saying that the circles only touch pairwise tangentially is fine, but I want the interior of any two circles to not intersect. And "finding a pattern" assumes that it is easily solvable for each $n.$ But is it easily solvable for each $n?$ I don't think it's easily solvable.

perhaps one of the sequences referenced at the bottom of https://oeis.org/A250001 could be useful

"Having the next circle fill a hole" means you have no restriction on the radius of the next circle, right? Just confirming that you are not given n known circles and you have to find the maximum enclosed places for that combination of known circles

Couls you provide a drawing ? Because I don't see how more than 4 disks can all be pairwise (externally) tangent.

@JeanMarie done. And Srini, yes the radii can all be different

Observation: There are two underlying planar graphs necessarily satisfying Euler's formula $V−E+F=2$. One for the tangent circles, and one for the adjacent regions.

We are tasked with finding the maximum number of enclosed gaps or holes formed by $n$ touching circles, where the configuration can be represented by a planar graph.
First, recall Euler's formula:
$$V - E + F = 2$$
where $V$ is the number of vertices, $E$ is the number of edges, and $F$ is the number of faces (including the outer region).
To maximize the number of enclosed regions or holes, we must maximize the number of faces $F$, while ensuring the graph remains planar. The maximum number of edges $E_{\text{max}}$ in a planar graph is given by Euler's bound:
$$E_{\text{max}} \leq 3V - 6$$
A maximally triangulated planar graph has $E = 3V - 6$, where each face is a triangle (i.e., a 3-cycle).
Substituting into Euler's formula:
$$
V - (3V - 6) + F = 2
$$
Simplifying for $F$:
$$
F = 2 + (3V - 6) - V = 2V - 4
$$
Thus, the maximum number of faces is $F = 2V - 4$. Since the outer face is not counted as an enclosed hole, the number of enclosed holes is:
$\text{Number of holes} = F - 1 = 2V - 5$
Therefore, the maximum number of enclosed holes for $n$ touching circles is:
$$2n - 5$$
You may also find interest in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_network
